# elastichsearch high open_contexts on one node

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a node on my cluster that is problematic. Sometimes the master can not join this node timeout (15s). I see clearly that it is more loaded than the others at the level of the search (open_contexts). Normally the load is well distributed on the nodes. Is it possible to clear pending search or should I need to restart node ?

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/0om1OiisRmqTH5fFSK8wsg/stats/indices/search?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "prd",
  "nodes" : {
    "0om1OiisRmqTH5fFSK8wsg" : {
      "timestamp" : 1522936494647,
      "name" : "web02",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/10.0.16.35:9300]",
      "host" : "web02",
      "ip" : [ "inet[/10.0.16.35:9300]", "NONE" ],
      "attributes" : {
        "master" : "false"
      },
      "indices" : {
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 523,
          "query_total" : 2026116995,
          "query_time_in_millis" : 12817060263,
          "query_current" : 2,
          "fetch_total" : 1279859730,
          "fetch_time_in_millis" : 14611437592,
          "fetch_current" : 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/hdBZdFOSTfKcm-An09A2XQ/stats/indices/search?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "prd",
  "nodes" : {
    "hdBZdFOSTfKcm-An09A2XQ" : {
      "timestamp" : 1522936492497,
      "name" : "web01",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/10.0.16.34:9300]",
      "host" : "web01",
      "ip" : [ "inet[/10.0.16.34:9300]", "NONE" ],
      "attributes" : {
        "master" : "false"
      },
      "indices" : {
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 6,
          "query_total" : 1076541870,
          "query_time_in_millis" : 4098363087,
          "query_current" : 3,
          "fetch_total" : 759295305,
          "fetch_time_in_millis" : 3333687709,
          "fetch_current" : 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you add the version of elasticsearch ?

Comment: thank you for your question, it's an old version : 1.7.5